# Avoiding pairwise analysis in count data?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, count-data, genetics

I'm having some trouble choosing an appropriate analysis method for some count data that I have. I'm looking at mutation counts in 50 genes across 6 related disease states. Counts range from 0 to ~400 in around 4000 observations. I am interested performing significance testing to determine if any mutations cluster within any of the disease states (or in more than one) or the other tail, that certain mutations are excluded in particular conditions (i.e. non-independent).

I have seen people apply repeated use of Fisher's exact test to calculate the odds ratios and P-values for this kind of data. My understanding is that to follow this method I would need to generate hundreds of contingency tables of Gene X vs Non-Gene X against Condition Y vs Non-Condition Y (something that I'd like to avoid). Furthermore, I'm concerned that this would not survive Bonferroni correction. Same goes for Chi Sq or G-test I fear.

Many answers on here recommend Poisson modelling for count data. I'm also unsure whether it's appropriate given that mean and variance might be different so NBD might be a goer. However, I'm not sure how either of these would be applied to the data set without the kind of binomial Gene 1 vs Non-Gene 1... Gene N vs Non-Gene N comparisons that I'm trying to avoid.

Is there any other way to pick out the gene-condition combinations that are non-independent? Or is this completely unrealistic?

Comment: Look at section 2.4 here, page 5 for some citations to methods that might be of use to you: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0907.2478.pdf.

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for the link. I used Benjamani-Hochberg when I was looking at my 50 genes x 50 genes for co-occurence. Given that it was 1225 comparisons, that seemed appropriate. Is BH appropriate for only 300 comparisons? The only experience I've had with BH is with RNAseq differential expression analysis (which again numbers in the thousands).